# Passing an java.awt.Image in ParameterMap to JasperReport on JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, ws-client

I'm looking for a solution to a problem.

I have a report on my `JasperReports Server`.

I want to pass an image to this report via the parameterMap.

What I've found so far is that I have to pass an `java.awt.Image` to the parameterMap.

so:

```java
java.awt.Image Image = new Image();

parameterMap.put("IMAGE",Image);
```

I execute the report via the `WSClient`.

The input parameter in the report for this is a `java.lang.Objec`t (e.g. "IMAGE").

```xml
<parameter name="IMAGE" class="java.lang.Object"/>
```

The image in the report should have the expression class `java.awt.Image`, and the image expression *`$P{IMAGE}`*.

```xml
        <image onErrorType="Blank">
            <reportElement key="image-1" x="440" y="0" width="94" height="118"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <imageExpression class="java.awt.Image"><![CDATA[$P{IMAGE}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
```

This solution works for `JasperReports` executed *on a local machine*, but not while passing the parametermap via the webservice-client to the `JasperReports Server`.

I get following exception:

```
    ERROR EngineServiceImpl,http-80-9:750 - Error while filling report
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
        Source text : $P{IMAGE}
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:195)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:589)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:557)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:929)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:1023)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:1004)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:258)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBandNoOverflow(JRVerticalFiller.java:439)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:403)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:264)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:128)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:118)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:435)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:773)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:731)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:389)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.executeReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:890)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.domain.impl.ReportUnitRequest.execute(ReportUnitRequest.java:57)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:320)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.ws.axis2.ManagementServiceImpl.runReport(ManagementServiceImpl.java:1167)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.ws.axis2.ManagementService.runReport(ManagementService.java:240)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor587.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
        at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:453)
        at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.common.UploadMultipartFilter.doFilter(UploadMultipartFilter.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:394)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
        at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(MetadataAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:139)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.PasswordExpirationProcessingFilter.doFilter(PasswordExpirationProcessingFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.basicauth.BasicProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(BasicProcessingFilter.java:174)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.JIPortletAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(JIPortletAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.filter.BasicLoggingFilter.doFilter(BasicLoggingFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
        at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
        at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:406)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.security.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.awt.Image
        at Onlinebewerbung_1328089933967_573349.evaluate(Onlinebewerbung_1328089933967_573349:235)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:182)
        ... 86 more
2012-02-01 10:52:14,091 ERROR ManagementServiceImpl,http-80-9:1259 - caught Throwable exception: Error evaluating expression : 
        Source text : $P{IMAGE}
```

Are there any ideas or known solutions for this problem?

Best regards,
Johann